# App crashing on iPhone 5 6.1.4 but works fine on others

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, iphone-5

I'm in the midst of submitting my first app so I'm definitely still learning alot as I go along. I just received the app rejection note that my app:

We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.4
Your app crashed when the alarm was supposed to ring.

This occurred when your app was used:

- On Wi-Fi
- On cellular network

I attached the crash report here and I hope someone might be able to help on how I might go about fixing this!! It works fine on all other versions and unfortunately I dont have an iPhone5 6.1.4 to test this on so never noticed it!! Thinking if it has something to do with the CFRunLoop?

Thanks!

```
Incident Identifier: 813F546D-237B-4761-BCE4-85EF4A21AEA1
CrashReporter Key:   faf5c17d0c159e839c86919af387d69d056f9fe5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         Torchie [11845]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/B2291BEB-8F50-43D8-BC90-7292ACB17362/Torchie.app/Torchie
Identifier:      Torchie
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-08-06 14:28:00.238 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32bf129e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aa9597a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   AVFoundation                    0x31d76d36 -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:] + 130
3   Torchie                         0x00098184 -[TorchieViewController torch:] (TorchieViewController.m:181)
4   Torchie                         0x00098756 -[TorchieViewController ringFlash] (TorchieViewController.m:275)
5   Foundation                      0x33508f4e __NSFireTimer + 58
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc65da __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
7   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc628c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 268
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc4efc __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32b37eb8 0x32b2f000 + 36536
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32b37d44 0x32b2f000 + 36164
11  GraphicsServices                0x366ec2e6 0x366e7000 + 21222
12  UIKit                           0x34a4d2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
13  Torchie                         0x00097026 main (main.m:16)
14  Torchie                         0x00096fdc start + 36


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af93350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3af0a11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3af4696e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a4e4d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a4e1ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aa95a74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a4e2078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a4e2110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a4e3594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aa959cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x32b37f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32b37d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x366ec2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x34a4d2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  Torchie                         0x00097026 main (main.m:16)
15  Torchie                         0x00096fdc start + 36

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af83648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aeb3974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aeb3654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af93d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aee1cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aee1a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aee18a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af82eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af83048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc6040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc4d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32b37eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32b37d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x38b27500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec30e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af9308c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aee4d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeeef14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   CoreMedia                       0x3311d8ac FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 256
4   MediaToolbox                    0x33c0fe56 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 22
5   CoreMedia                       0x3313b890 figThreadMain + 192
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec30e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  AQClient
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af82eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3af83048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc6040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32bc4d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32b37eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32b37d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   AudioToolbox                    0x326196fe GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 134
7   AudioToolbox                    0x325fa882 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 294
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec30e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aeec1d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3ca89534
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ca89b88      r6: 0x1e5953b4      r7: 0x2fd6ba24
    r8: 0x1e595390    r9: 0x00000300     r10: 0x1f067260     r11: 0x1f05aa30
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd6ba18      lr: 0x3af0a123      pc: 0x3af93350
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x95000 -    0xa1fff +Torchie armv7  <0bfcf99566bf341b8b76e2eea17e15e6> /var/mobile/Applications/B2291BEB-8F50-43D8-BC90-7292ACB17362/Torchie.app/Torchie
0x2fe7b000 - 0x2fe9b75b  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31d12000 - 0x31df8fff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31df9000 - 0x31df9fff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31dfa000 - 0x31f38ff3  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31f39000 - 0x3201cff7  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3201d000 - 0x322d2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x322d3000 - 0x3232cff3  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3232d000 - 0x3233efff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x3233f000 - 0x3233ffff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32340000 - 0x32351ffe  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x32353000 - 0x323b7ffb  AddressBook armv7  <8cfae84dc66d3c1f9d17335c53c3d7b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x323b8000 - 0x32472fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x32473000 - 0x32481ffc  AssetsLibrary armv7  <9a3a4a47a77833eb82a28757a3488660> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x325bd000 - 0x32845ff7  AudioToolbox armv7  <394ee11cf826367db9ff4968dbc71d6d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32846000 - 0x3290bff7  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3290c000 - 0x32962ff8  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x32976000 - 0x32b2e49f  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32b2f000 - 0x32c61ff1  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32c62000 - 0x32d9afff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32d9c000 - 0x32dd7ff0  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x32fbb000 - 0x32fd6ffb  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x32fd7000 - 0x3308cff2  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x3308d000 - 0x330e5ff7  CoreLocation armv7  <4edb4b0f05e13af8b84699fe3ea4c538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3311a000 - 0x3317fff2  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33180000 - 0x33208ff3  CoreMotion armv7  <4512d901170d32e7842e7fc1c519386b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x33209000 - 0x3325fffb  CoreTelephony armv7  <bea09dbe25363c3b8e8016b5b5148055> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33260000 - 0x332c2fff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x332c3000 - 0x332d2fff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x332d3000 - 0x33387fff  EventKit armv7  <99a7a1603323319f9e24f97e9f89bfd3> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x33457000 - 0x3361affd  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x337d5000 - 0x3381efff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3381f000 - 0x339f7ffb  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33a71000 - 0x33c0bfff  MediaPlayer armv7  <ce97a30e514d3a17ae93ba4a9d1d69d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x33c0c000 - 0x33e86ff7  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33e87000 - 0x33f0dfff  MessageUI armv7  <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33f0e000 - 0x33f67ff7  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x34056000 - 0x3405dfff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3405f000 - 0x3405ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x34063000 - 0x34065ffd  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x34066000 - 0x3406afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3406b000 - 0x340a8ff9  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x347a3000 - 0x348b8fff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x348b9000 - 0x34906fff  QuickLook armv7  <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x34907000 - 0x34935ffc  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x34936000 - 0x349a3fff  Social armv7  <7b778c6ce3433df18ef0892acd831208> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x349b4000 - 0x349f3fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x349f6000 - 0x34f4aff3  UIKit armv7  <ad8b3ad23f413187a178179db39cfa6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34f4b000 - 0x34f89ff3  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x351fb000 - 0x35207ffb  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3524e000 - 0x35251fff  ActorKit armv7  <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x35253000 - 0x35256ffb  AggregateDictionary armv7  <c2a6c1ff89a9318d8b74fc5dfc8847b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3533f000 - 0x35352ff8  AirTraffic armv7  <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x35682000 - 0x356bdfff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x356be000 - 0x356e2ffc  AppleAccount armv7  <c54536fbc0f235f693060be33d4d4749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x356ef000 - 0x356fcffa  ApplePushService armv7  <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x35730000 - 0x35739ffb  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3573a000 - 0x35753ff8  AssistantServices armv7  <9608ae74229e3daeab9c8fcf679de7d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x35769000 - 0x35780fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <772912697ec23e5199a452e97f075dd9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x3578a000 - 0x357aeff7  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x357c1000 - 0x357f0ffb  BulletinBoard armv7  <9f46015c5d263064901f7725f4bb93e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x3582e000 - 0x35835ffa  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35836000 - 0x35900ffe  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x3590d000 - 0x35911fff  CertUI armv7  <ce979f715cdb3cb5a0f7935f14cc0b35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x359b7000 - 0x359d0ff9  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <ec2f76b3ac723a39bbf3f122d7fe73cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x359e4000 - 0x359e9fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x35a6e000 - 0x35a9eff5  ContentIndex armv7  <00ed488e47ee34ca9f01f2cc911f453c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x35b1a000 - 0x35c02ffe  CoreMediaStream armv7  <828bf27fe7a3337cbff7dd8837508819> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x35caf000 - 0x35cb0ffd  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35d18000 - 0x35d1cffc  CoreTime armv7  <5f0b123555f03d8aa76cc54314907942> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x35d1d000 - 0x35d22fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35d23000 - 0x35d5fffb  DataAccess armv7  <d7185042adf63908ae87fe4a5c3f8a6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35ef4000 - 0x35f06fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x35f45000 - 0x35f46ffc  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x35f49000 - 0x35f62ff9  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x35f6a000 - 0x35f82ff4  EAP8021X armv7  <6d5ab53850e23fe389e64e2705bd7810> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35f92000 - 0x35f96fff  FTClientServices armv7  <6354e5b30919340db3b976312b284fce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x35f97000 - 0x35fd4fff  FTServices armv7  <89c066d12a6031038a9b8c61221abc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35fd5000 - 0x363e8ffd  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x365e0000 - 0x365ecffe  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x365ed000 - 0x366e6fff  GeoServices armv7  <edbf37a31a6a31f49e392ed8ece200c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x366e7000 - 0x366f2fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36761000 - 0x367dcfff  HomeSharing armv7  <280b77b71df23f1cb5c9a2b76fc53212> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x367dd000 - 0x367e7ffd  IAP armv7  <a9554a91bbb9308f96fcd9fddf596275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3689f000 - 0x36917fff  IMCore armv7  <d5f1d98ec53d3acbb51b116e93923d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x369de000 - 0x36a2afff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36a31000 - 0x36a32ffc  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x36a33000 - 0x36a38ffa  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59>
```

This is the last method in my code before the crash:

```
-(void)torch:(BOOL)isOn { 
    torchIsOn = isOn; 
    [self strobeOff]; 
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil]; 
    if (isOn) { 
        [slider setHidden:NO]; 
        [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:[slider value] error:nil]; 
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(torch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
    }
    else { 
        [device setTorchMode:NO]; 
    } 

    [device unlockForConfiguration]; 
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for having enough sense to symbolicate the crash report before posting it (A lot of new people don't do that).  However, it would be useful if you let is know what is happening inside of `torch:`

Comment: Please edit the question and format the code instead of posting it as a comment.  I think you can see that it is hard to read this way

Comment: I will show you what I mean.  I will edit your question...

Comment: -(void)torch:(BOOL)isOn
{
    torchIsOn = isOn;
    [self strobeOff];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (isOn) {
        [slider setHidden:NO];
        [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:[slider value] error:nil];
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(torch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }else{
        [device setTorchMode:NO];
    }

    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}

Comment: thanks man. so sorry i'm trying to be honest i'm not sure how to do it within the comment box as u did in your 'torch:'

Comment: thanks @borrrden for helping with tt part of the post!

Comment: That's because you don't do it as a comment.  You press the "edit" button under your question and change it.

Comment: I love how they don't give you the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making these checks in your `torch:` method before setting your torch mode.

`[device hasTorch]` and `[device torchAvailable]` and `[device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]`

The torch may not be available for use. This may be causing the crash. Note that [device torchAvailable] is iOS 5 and up.

from the [AVCaptureDevice class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Even if the device has a torch, that torch might not be available for use. Thus, you should also check the value of the torchAvailable property before using it.

so your torch: method could look like:

```
-(void)torch:(BOOL)isOn { 
    torchIsOn = isOn; 
    [self strobeOff]; 
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil]; 

    if (isOn && [device hasTorch] && [device torchAvailable] && [device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) { 
        [slider setHidden:NO]; 
        [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:[slider value] error:nil]; 
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(torch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
    }
    else { 
        [device setTorchMode:NO]; 
    } 

    [device unlockForConfiguration]; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I edited my code up top does it seem to cover that now?

Comment: probably want to add check for [device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn] as well. But in your question post you don't want to include code edits from my answer... you want to show the code for torch: that actually ran to cause the crash.

Comment: oo wow ok i'll try out your suggestion thanks. but that said, I'm unsure as to why Apple mentioned the crash occurred on iPhone 5 6.1.4 and unfortunately i dont have one on that iOS so i cant test it out. it worked fine beforehand on all my other devices and iOS haha.

Comment: check out the comments in AVCaptureDevice.h from Apple on using the setTorchModeOnWithLevel method. You'll see it might not be available if the device is too hot, even. So.. you could easily miss this in testing even if you had the right device, cos its not common or even completely deterministic how to recreate that scenario. Kudos to Apple for even mentioning that in their comments. Use those checks and you should be fine, imo.

Comment: appreciate the comments and notes! Made the changes alr hopefully it will prevent the crashes from happening again haha. Thanks!